# Adding custom language dialect in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I was doing localization of an app in which I face an issue regarding dialects of a country's language. My main question is, is there any provision of adding custom language.

Eg:

Suppose there are two languages:

```
PL for Poland

UK for Ukraine
```

**I need to support pl-uk i.e Poland Ukraini**

Comment: His local is not offered by iOS thus the user could not even set his device to this local. So why add it? If you have your own local selector in your app you should just added it there.

Comment: yes actually I have local language setting, but the point is now to achieve it I am to add manually pl-uk.lproj to project. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `pl-UK.lproj` would have made sense if this dialect could be chosen from the system preferences, which is not the case. If you have a local setting, I'm afraid there's no other solution than managing the localisations yourself - and it won't work for Interface Builder files.

The simplest is to store all the `pl-UK` differences in a separate file (it can be a `.strings` that you store into the `pl.lproj` folder (that you localise in Polish Polish - to respect the semantics of the system). Then in a custom function, you load those strings:

```
func localize(_ string : String, comment: comment) {
    guard !isUkrainianPolish else {
       return NSLocalizedString(string, comment: comment)
    }
    // retrieve the cache and check if a key with string exists

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "localizable_pl_UK" /* or any other name*/, withExtension: "strings", subdirectory: nil, localization:"pl"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let plist = (try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil)) as? [String:String] {
        // cache the dictionary where you want
        return plist[string] ?? NSLocalizedString(string, comment: comment)
    }
}
```

Depending on the organisation of your code, you can implement the function in a singleton or the class that handle localizations.

Comment: Yes Renaud, I think this is the only option.